# Can a Certificate be generated in Java, without using sun internal code, keytool, or bouncycastle

Tags: java

I am trying to generate a certificate that can be used with an SSL/TLS socket on a network application (find more info [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/76959/what-is-the-security-value-of-this-on-the-fly-user-registration)).

I have generated an RSA 1024-bit KeyPair with

```
public KeyPair generateKeyPair(final String algorithm, final int bitLength) throws 
    NoSuchAlgorithmException {
    final KeyPairGenerator generator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance(algorithm);
    generator.initialize(bitLength);
    return generator.generateKeyPair();
}
```

And trying to generate the certificate with

```
private static Certificate generateCertificate(final PublicKey publicKey) throws 
    CertificateException {
    X509EncodedKeySpec spec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(publicKey.getEncoded());
    final ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(spec.getEncoded());

    final CertificateFactory factory = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
    final Certificate cert = factory.generateCertificate(bais);
    return cert;
}
```

but doing this gives me a

```
java.security.cert.CertificateException: Unable to initialize, java.io.IOException: DerInputStream.getLength(): lengthTag=127, too big.
at sun.security.x509.X509CertImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.provider.X509Factory.engineGenerateCertificate(Unknown Source)
at java.security.cert.CertificateFactory.generateCertificate(Unknown Source)
at net.zephyrion.ssl.SSLServer.generateCertificate(SSLServer.java:123)
at net.zephyrion.ssl.SSLServer.processKeyStore(SSLServer.java:86)
at net.zephyrion.ssl.SSLServer.main(SSLServer.java:41)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: DerInputStream.getLength(): lengthTag=127, too big.
at sun.security.util.DerInputStream.getLength(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.util.DerValue.<init>(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.util.DerInputStream.getDerValue(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.x509.X509CertImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
... 6 more
```

I've looked around, and the last answer about this was in 2009. I want it to be as lightweight as possible, so I don't want to use bouncycastle, and I want it to use pure public Java API, so no sun internal code, and I don't want to use an external process, so not keytool.

I am using Java 7 for this until Java 8 is released publicly, but even then, would the framework be available to do this?

Answer (score 0):

First at all your snippet is incorrect:

```
X509EncodedKeySpec spec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(publicKey.getEncoded());
final ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(spec.getEncoded());

final CertificateFactory factory = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
final Certificate cert = factory.generateCertificate(bais);
```

generateCertificate expects DER encoded certificate stream, not public key as in here.

and a lot of logic goes in how to produce that DER encoded stream ( not part of public API )

I would really, really suggest you to use a good third party library to do this.

Comment: That much I can tell. Perhaps I should have worded that portion, how would I create a DerInputStream from a PublicKey.